Provide a concise example of how to use rsyslog's immark module
I am seeking a working example that uses the immark module of rsyslog.  I tried this nonsensical example just to see what it does:
# maybe in a file called "immark.test"
module(load="immark" interval="2")
*.* /tmp/test-mark.out

Running this as
rsyslog -iNONE -dnf immark.test

does show that rsyslogd is receiving a signal (SIGTTOU) every 2 seconds, but nothing is written to /tmp/test-mark.out.  I may be very mistaken about how it works and what it supposed to do.  It would not be the first time I am surprised by rsyslogd behavior, syntax, etc.
What I expected was that every 2 seconds or so, rsyslogd would receive a "mark message" (which apparently it IS doing) and then write whatever content it receives (I believe it is something like "-- MARK --") to the output file /tmp/test-mark.out.  Ultimately, I would be sending a "heartbeat" message to a tool.
I have read, and re-read, the documentation on immark several times now, and I have been searching the web for pertinent hints and tips, and while it sounds like it might do what I am looking for, maybe this is not what it is supposed to do and I need to figure out an alternative.  (An alternative that works with rsyslog, that is.)
I do note that the rsyslog documentation says that the "mark" facility is deprecated, but I wonder why it is still documented if not for continued support of existing users of immark.
Any help would be appreciated: Additional documentation, or a very concise snippet.  I would prefer Rainerscript if possible, but at this point, I will be grateful for anything.

I had the exact same problem on Ubuntu server 22.04. Only mark messages was generated when I restarted rsyslog but not in the interval I defined. The MARK log is written to syslog (/var/log/syslog) as info
But when I in /etc/rsyslog.conf uncomment the immark WITHOUT the inteval - then it seems to work with the 1200 sek default interval BUT only repeated 1 time ... DOH! (
SO as an ALTERNATIVE i made a cronjob with a specified interval and use the command as seen here (this on sends a mark log every 30 min at time 00 and 30):
/30 * * * * logger -p syslog.info -t ${0##/}[$$] MARK
I will get back if i find the reason for the missing stability of the immark function

Thank you for looking into this.  I also thought of using cron as a workaround, but it sort of defeats the purpose.  I am seeking the most efficient means, and I see invoking cron as a bit clumsy.
